# Parse Razor string in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, razorengine

In ASP.NET MVC I could parse Razor scripts like this:

```
string template = "It is @DateTime.Now.ToString()";
string result = Razor.Parse(template);
```

But this static doesn't exist in core.

Also I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32558941/1305969), but in my case the view code is a string, so I can't use the `find` or `get` view methods from the `ICompositeViewEngine`.

Any advice on how to get a view string parsed in core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render Razor view to string in ASP.NET 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362156/render-razor-view-to-string-in-asp-net-5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render Razor View to string in ASP.NET Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558941/render-razor-view-to-string-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 5):

I've already answered the question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558941/render-razor-view-to-string-in-asp-net-core/38551544#38551544)

> Today I've finished with my library that can solve your problem. You can use it out of ASP.NET as it has no
>   dependencies on it

This is how you can use it

```
string template = "It is @DateTime.Now.ToString()";
string result = new LightRazorEngine().ParseString(template);
```

More: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight