# In ASP.NET Core, I want to update the generate HTML After Razor is done

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

After the razor engine is done processing my HTML, I want to grab that HTML and add some text right after the closing  tag.  I assume I can do that someplace in services but can't figure out where.

Comment: What is the purpose of that? Your approach is quite unusual... Why can't you do that (adding that text after closing tag) in the Partial View/View which you are returning (for example basing on some model variable)?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I'm building a tag helper to aid in script management.  I collect all the scripts used (including inside tag helpers) to track the javascript includes. I did figure out how to use the middleware to do this.  The project is here:  https://github.com/pkellner/ScriptManagerTagHelper/tree/feature-peterupdatesbig  The reason I can't do it in partial view is that the script tags could be anyplace.

Comment: So try to render razor view into string (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362156/render-razor-view-to-string-in-asp-net-5), then add what you need and send it to the browser.

Comment: Thanks @DawidRutkowski   In my github project I did something smilar but as a pipeline step which I believe is the more intended way of adding things.